# ckeditor config.protectedSource dont work for html element attributes on editor.insertHtml

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I've updated ckeditor from 4.0 to 4.5.4 and now my plugin dont work as before.

In my config.js i have

```
    config.protectedSource.push(  /\{[\s\S]*?\}/g );
```

So i wan't to protect all {} (smarty stuff) in the edit mode.

Next is my Code from the dialog button.

```
                onOk: function () {
                    var currentTabId = this._.currentTabId;
                    var link = '';
                    var OXID = this.getContentElement(currentTabId, 'OXID').getValue();
                    link += "{assign var=\"aSb_cms_data\" value=$oViewConf->sb_cms_getCategorieData('" + OXID + "')}";

                    link += "<a href='{$aSb_cms_data.link}'";

                    title = "{$aSb_cms_data.title}";

                    link += 'title="' + title + '">' + title;
                    link += "</a>"

                    console.log(link); //
                    editor.insertHtml(link); 
                }
```

console.log(link) will output:

```
    {assign var="aSb_cms_data" value=$oViewConf->sb_cms_getCategorieData('testid')}<a href='{$aSb_cms_data.link}'title="{$aSb_cms_data.title}">{$aSb_cms_data.title}</a>
```

That's what i want in the source code.

But in the Source Code(ckeditor) is now:

```
 {assign var="aSb_cms_data" value=$oViewConf->sb_cms_getCategorieData('testid')}<a href="&lt;!--{cke_protected}%7B%24aSb_cms_data.link%7D--&gt;" title="&lt;!--{cke_protected}%7B%24aSb_cms_data.title%7D--&gt;">{$aSb_cms_data.title}</a>
```

All "a" attributes are messed up with cke_protected stuff...
at V4.0 the sourcecode was equal to the console.log output.

How can i fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the Problem:

there is a missing whitespace at

```
link += 'title="' + title + '">' + title;
```

before the Title:

```
link += ' title="' + title + '">' + title;
```

that's all.